# How to replace all the matched characters in a string using replace?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a method I am using to format the date in a Google Apps Script so that it just reads `MMM dd, yyyy`. I am trying to replace all the "-"s in my date string with "" but using the replace method only replaces the first "-" of the string and none of the rest. Any thoughts as to why that is? How can I get it to replace all the "-" in my string?

Here is my code:

```
function formatDate() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 9);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange); 

  //Format date in column D
  for(var k=0; k<objects.length; k++){
    var column = data[k];
    var DateCell = column[4];
    var emailSent = column[8];


    var column = data[k];
    var DateCell = column[4];
    var date = new Date(DateCell).toLocaleDateString('en-US',{
      day : 'numeric',
      month : 'short',
      year : 'numeric'
      }).split("").join("-").replace(/-/g, "");

    var Date1 = dataSheet.getRange(startRow + k, 5);
    var Date2 = dataSheet.getRange(startRow + k, 6);
    Date1.setValue(date);
    Date2.setValue(date);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these snippets work.

```js
var str = "testing-this-out";

var beforeEl = document.getElementById("before");

var afterEl = document.getElementById("after");

beforeEl.innerText = "Before: " + str;

afterEl.innerText = "After: " + str.replace(/([-])+/g, "");
```

```html
<p id="before"></p>
<p id="after"></p>
```

```js
var date = new Date("2017-01-11").toLocaleDateString('en-US',{
  day : 'numeric',
  month : 'short',
  year : 'numeric'
}).split("").join("-").replace(/([-])/g, "");

document.getElementById("date").innerText = date;
```

```html
<span id="date"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kyle Richardson I tried your suggestion and for some reason now its not formatting the date at all.

Comment: that is odd, let me show it inside a runnable snippet

Comment: i'll work on the date string for you, I didn't see that part.

Comment: what does a DateCell look like

Comment: The DateCell is a date object in the format 4/1/2017. its from a Google form input. I am copying it from column[4] of the response spreadsheet. I then copy the info and send an email on form submit but when I do it sends the entire date format Sat Apr 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT). This is why I started to reformat it. Using Utilities.formatDate did not work either, so I tried to change it to a string and do it that way, hence here we are.

Comment: I think the issue is coming from the DateCell being a google form calendar object and not a date string. Does that sound right? I'm new to javascript and appscript so don't really understand.

Comment: When I run the code in your snippet and replace the DateCell with a string "2017-01-11" I get InvalidDate in spreadsheet data.

Comment: Why is this answer marked as "correct" when it (a) apparently didn't solve the problem and (b) is not in the same language / dialect as the OP's question? (...which had invalid tags on it in the first place)